# how to count the number of given characters in a list of characters?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am new in Racket and wanna make a function called occurrences which would count how many times a character appears in a list of characters. For example :

> (occurrences '(#\a #\a #\b) #\a)

> 2 ; this should be the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with [foldl](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29), like so:

```
(define (occurrences l c) 
   (foldl (lambda (x acc) (if (char=? x c) (+ acc 1) acc)) 0 l))
(writeln (occurrences '(#\a#\a#\b) #\a))
```

Fold will start count from zero and increment for each item that matches the required value